# How can I create a calculated column only if the current column shares a field the same as 2 previous columns in R?

Tags: r

If anyone has a better suggestion for a title please let me know.

I have a dataset that looks like the below, I need to add Value1 for the current and previous 2 quarters to value 2 for the current quarter, but only for the same dimension. No value should be entered if the previous quarters could not be found.

Dataset:

```
Dimension, Date, Value1, Value2
1, 7/31/2001, 10, 20
1, 10/31/2001, 10, 30
1, 1/31/2002, 10, 40
1, 4/30/2002, 20, 20
1, 7/31/2003, 20, 40
2, 12/31/2002, 30, 20
2, 3/31/2003, 10, 20
2, 6/30/2003, 20, 20
2, 9/30/2003, 40, 10
```

Desired Output:

```
Dimension, Date, Value1, Value2, Goal
1, 7/31/2001, 10, 20, 50
1, 10/31/2001, 10, 30, 70 
1, 1/31/2002, 10, 40, 90
1, 4/30/2002, 20, 20, NA
1, 7/31/2003, 20, 40, NA
2, 12/31/2002, 30, 20, 80
2, 3/31/2003, 10, 20, 80
2, 6/30/2003, 20, 20, 90
2, 9/30/2003, 40, 10, NA
```

dput version

Input

```
structure(list(Dimension = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Date = c("7/31/2001", "10/31/2001", "1/31/2002", "4/30/2002", 
"7/31/2003", "12/31/2002", "3/31/2003", "6/30/2003", "9/30/2003"
), Value1 = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 40L), Value2 = c(20L, 
30L, 40L, 20L, 40L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 10L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("Dimension", 
"Date", "Value1", "Value2"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    Dimension = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Value1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Value2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("Dimension", "Date", "Value1", 
"Value2")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Output

```
structure(list(Dimension = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Date = c("7/31/2001", "10/31/2001", "1/31/2002", "4/30/2002", 
"7/31/2003", "12/31/2002", "3/31/2003", "6/30/2003", "9/30/2003"
), Value1 = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 10L, 20L, 40L), Value2 = c(20L, 
30L, 40L, 20L, 40L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 10L), Goal = c(50L, 70L, 90L, 
NA, NA, 80L, 80L, 90L, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("Dimension", "Date", "Value1", 
"Value2", "Goal"), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(
    Dimension = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Value1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Value2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), Goal = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("Dimension", "Date", "Value1", 
"Value2", "Goal")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Can you add output of `dput` on your dataset?

Comment: I updated the question to include a dput version

Comment: Will there always be data for quarters consecutively, or is it possible for the data to skip a quarter(s) (like data just for 2nd and 4th quarter with 3rd quarter skipped)?

Comment: Also, do you mean "add Value1 for the current and __next__ 2 quarters"? otherwise your desired output seems off (I would expect `Goal` to be `NA` for the first two records)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, assuming you meant "add Value1 for the current and **next** 2 quarters" and that quarters will appear consecutively in the data, we can use the **`dplyr`** and **`lubridate`** packages.

First, we create `Year` and `Qtr` columns so that we can sort by these columns. Then, we `group_by` `Dimension`. Finally, we use the `lead` function to grab the next two values of `Value`.

```
library(dplyr);library(lubridate)

dat %>%
    mutate(Date = mdy(Date),
           Year = year(Date),
           Qtr = quarter(Date)) %>%
    arrange(Year, Qtr) %>%
    group_by(Dimension) %>%
    mutate(Goal = Value2 + Value1 + lead(Value1) + lead(Value1, 2)) %>%
    select(-Year, -Qtr)

  Dimension       Date Value1 Value2  Goal
      <int>     <date>  <int>  <int> <int>
1         1 2001-07-31     10     20    50
2         1 2001-10-31     10     30    70
3         1 2002-01-31     10     40    90
4         1 2002-04-30     20     20    NA
5         2 2002-12-31     30     20    80
6         2 2003-03-31     10     20    90
7         2 2003-06-30     20     20    NA
8         1 2003-07-31     20     40    NA
9         2 2003-09-30     40     10    NA
```